# Code not working when slicing string

Tags: string, python-2.7, slice

I'm doing an assignment for a Coursera python course and I dont know why I'm getting the error I'm getting.

The code is meant to extract a number from lines in file of name "mbox-short.txt", and then find the average of those numbers. I know how to do it but I'm getting a "bad input" error on line 14 (num = text[x:x+6]) when I run it.

Here is my code:

## Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
n = 0
total = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    text = line.strip()
    print text
    x = text.find('0')
    x = int(x)
    print x
    num = text[x:x+6]
    num = float(num)
    print num
    total = total + num
    n = n+1
ave = total/n
print "Average spam confidence:", ave
```

please help me :(

Comment: it might be helpful to also post the input line that poses problems and the complete error message...

Comment: i posted the input line: 

        num = text[x:x+6]

the complete error message is:

        ParseError: bad input on line 14

Comment: the file that is used is found here: http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt

Answer (score 0):

I just retyped it and it works now. Stupidest solution ever. Can't believe it.